# removing dates from Joomla URLs

Tags: seo, joomla3.0, sef

I imported posts from Wordpress to Joomla
I have created a category blog_post to which they are all assigned
I have not so far as I am aware set any option to adjust or set paramaters to effect the aliases and the alias are all of the format "this-is-the-title"

However in the SEF process, Joomla is adding the create date/time as a directory and then inserting the article number at the begining of the article 
Thus an article with an alias 
"mydomain.co.uk/Interesting-article-to-read" 
would become 
"mydomain.co.uk/2016-05-05-12-06-36/234Interesting-article-to-read"

If it makes a difference the Joomla is 3.5.1
I am not using any other re-writing product other than comes with joomla
Other pages and menus not imported do not display this behaviour.

I do have to have an entry in .haccess which converts the old blog alias from
myolddomain/year/alias to mydomain/alias however, I have tesed this and it is working well.

I am not an expert with Joomla by any means so any help greatfully received. 
Regards

Answer (score 0):

In the Joomla Global configuration page there is settings for url rewriting. Did you try that?
[image: Global Configuration->Site->SEO Settings]

I recommend you try this 
1. http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/site-management/url-redirection/non-sef-to-sef
2. http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/site-management/sef/sef-wizard-for-joomla

Comment: Thanks for the help, I worry that I am not explaining the problem fully. There are elements of the site that are using Joomla's sef to give sef  pages and the plugins you suggest may deliver that but I am not sure if it will unsettle those. I am trying to find a way to effectively just influence the articles assigned to a blog category or a single menu item as the other single articles seem to work fine.

I have tried all of your suggestions but have seen no change, but fully accept that may be my ignorance in setting up the plugins